# Erro conexão MYSQL no Android utilizando php

Tags: php, android, mysqli, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

Estou tentando conectar minha aplicação Android Java via php com meu banco MYSQL e inserir dados no mesmo, mas apesar da aplicação Android informar que o "usuário foi cadastrado com sucesso" os dados que tento inserir não aparecem no banco de dados.

Estou utilizando so seguintes códigos:

**Android Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText email, senha, cpf, telefone, membroDesde, nome, pontos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.senha);
    cpf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cpf);
    telefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefone);
    membroDesde = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.membroDesde);
    nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nome);
    pontos = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pontos);
}

public void cadastrar(View view) {
    String emailLogin = email.getText().toString();
    String senhaLogin = senha.getText().toString();
    String cpfLogin = cpf.getText().toString();
    String telefoneLogin = telefone.getText().toString();
    String membroDesdeLogin = membroDesde.getText().toString();
    String nomeLogin = nome.getText().toString();
    String pontosLogin = pontos.getText().toString();

    if (!(emailLogin.isEmpty()) && !(senhaLogin.isEmpty())) {
        Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
                .load("http://192.168.15.12/conexaoBanco/cadastro.php")
                .setBodyParameter("emailLogin", emailLogin)
                .setBodyParameter("cpfLogin", cpfLogin)
                .setBodyParameter("senhaLogin", senhaLogin)
                .setBodyParameter("telefoneLogin", telefoneLogin)
                .setBodyParameter("nomeLogin", nomeLogin)
                .setBodyParameter("membroDesdeLogin", membroDesdeLogin)
                .setBodyParameter("pontosLogin", pontosLogin)
                .asJsonObject()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                        try {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.sucessoCadastro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (Exception error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.errorCadastro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Todos os campos precisam ser preenchidos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} }
```

**cadastro.php**

/* código do arquivo conexao.php */

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "afiliado");

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    require 'conexao.php';
    insereAfiliado();
}
    function insereAfiliado()
    {
         global $connect;

```
     $nome = $_POST["nomeLogin"];
     $email = $_POST["emailLogin"];
     $cpf = $_POST["cpfLogin"];
     $senha = $_POST["senhaLogin"];
     $pontos = $_POST["pontosLogin"];
     $telefone = $_POST["telefoneLogin"];
     $membroDesde = $_POST["membroDesdeLogin"];

$query = "INSERT into afiliado (nome, cpf, pontos, telefone, email, senha, membro_desde) values ('$nome', '$cpf', '$pontos', '$telefone', '$email', '$senha', '$membro_desde')";


 mysqli_query($connect, $query) OR DIE(mysql_error($connect));
     var_dump(mysqli_query);
     mysqli_close($connect);  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro se deu primeiramente, porque o banco de dados apenas aceitou os dados como `varchar`, mesmo alguns campos sendo de outros tipos, e posteriormente por conta do firewall do Windows que estava travando a porta do servidor xampp.